# Disable all form elements but one

Tags: jquery

I use the following to disable all form elements within a table row:

```
$(".chkbx").change(function(){
    var $this  = $(this);
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Which it does great. The problem -- it disables ALL, including **.chkbx**. I need to keep the checkbox with this class (chkbx) always enabled. How do I exclude it from the function?

Comment: `$this.closest("tr").find(":input:not(.chkbx)")`? Or `$this.closest("tr").find(":input").not('.chkbx')`?

Answer (score 4):

I think using the `not` function like this would work

```
$this.closest("tr").find(":input").not(".chkbx").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add one more line to your existing code:

```
$(".chkbx").change(function(){
    var $this  = $(this);
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    $this.attr("disabled",false);
});
```

It's not optimal or efficient, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
$(".chkbx").change(function(){
    var $this  = $(this);
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input").attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $this.closest("tr").find(":input:not(.chkbx)").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

not sure if it will work! but give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like the following:

```
$('.chkbx').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
$(this).closest('tr').find('input,textarea,select').not($(this)).attr('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
$(this).closest('tr').find('input,textarea,select').not($(this)).attr('disabled',false);
        }
    });
```